# Is it possible to see less popular questions by tag/week/month/year?

Tags: discussion, questions, popularity

I was wondering whether it's possible to see the less popular questions by categories (tag, week, month, year).

This question might have already been asked but I could not find it.

Answer (score 2):

Less popular is often unanswered (or no serious answers). So you could try the unanswered questions per tag.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android.

Comment: yes but that get me the unanswered not the one with less popularity